# Javascript generated combo box order of item in chrome is upside down

Tags: javascript, combobox, google-chrome

I got a JavaScript code I wrote that calls a web service returns some data and populate the results in a combo box. However I ran into a problem where the ordering of items for the combo box is upside down in Google Chrome. In other browser such as IE and Opera it is in its order from the way the script populate the list of items.

I like to know is this a known issue with chrome itself or is it the way how chrome handles JavaScript.

Edit:
This is the function I call to add items to the combo box:

```
function addItemToDropList(comboBox, text, value) {
    var dropListItem = document.createElement('option');
    dropListItem.text = text;
    dropListItem.value = value;

    try
    {
    comboBox.options.add(dropListItem, null);
    }
    catch(e)
    {
        comboBox.options.add(dropListItem);
    }    
}
```

Comment: Have you tried Firefox? It is probably the most singularly popular browser and it is often used as a "standard" to work off in development.

Comment: @Kerry
As for firefox, XMLHttpRequest doesn't even make the call to the web service to retrieve the data. But on all the other browser works perfectly fine.

Comment: @madness800 if you're testing the page from a file:// URL, then the web service looks to Firefox like something in a different domain, and it won't make the request. Once you deploy to a real site, it will have to be in the exact same domain as your web service anyway.

Comment: @Pointy I'm testing the my page on local IIS, also my web service is running on the same domain.

Comment: That "add" function you're calling on the options collection is not standard.  IE supports it, but the WebKit browsers may simply implement it differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming the `comboBox` variable in your code snippet is the `<select>` element. If so, you should be able to use this:

```
comboBox.appendChild(dropListItem);
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a problem with chrome.  see [Google Chrome: JavaScript associative arrays, evaluated out of sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/640745/google-chrome-javascript-associative-arrays-evaluated-out-of-sequence)