# Change in order for .each() in firefox and chrome

Tags: jquery, each

I have a web service that returns a JSON encoded array of data. I then use jQuery's `.each()` function to iterate through that array but in Firefox it iterates down while in Chrome it iterates up.

the data that come sback from the web service is:

```
{
  "data": {
    "610": {
      "id": "610",
      "url": "a url 1",
      "description": "XXX YYY",
      "toc": "0000-01-00",
      "active": "1"
    },
    "608": {
      "id": "608",
      "url": "a url 1",
      "description": "ytttgffrr",
      "toc": "0000-01-00",
      "active": "1"
    },
    "607": {
      "id": "607",
      "url": "a url  3",
      "description": "rtretert3",
      "toc": "0000-01-00",
      "active": "1"
    },
    "606": {
      "id": "606",
      "url": "a url 4",
      "description": "xxxwwww",
      "toc": "0000-01-00",
      "active": "1"
    },
    ...
  }
}
```

Firefox goes 610 -> 606 while chrome fors 606 -> 610.

Any ideas why and what I can do about it?

Comment: maybe related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/640745/google-chrome-javascript-associative-arrays-evaluated-out-of-sequence

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/648139/is-the-order-of-fields-in-a-javascript-object-predictable-when-looping-through-t

Answer (score 7):

Properties in objects have no inherent order. The ECMAScript specification doesn’t guarantee that `for…in` statements will traverse the object by its properties in alphabetical order. [`jQuery.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each) uses `for…in` under the hood when used on objects.

If the order is important to you, use an array instead of an object.

Comment: @Matt Did you edit my post just so you could remove your upvote? Classy.

Answer (score 0):

Property enumeration does not have any guaranteed order. If you want to enumerate over properties in a guaranteed order, put the properites of the object in an array, sort them as you expect and then enumerate over that.

In ES5, you can do this simply using [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys);

```
var keys = Object.keys(yourObj).sort();

for (var i=0;i<keys.length;i++) {
    // use yourObj[keys[i]]; guaranteed to be in the right order
}
```

If you're not using an HTML5 shim or can't use the [`Object.keys()` polyfiller](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys#Compatiblity), a `for in` will suffice;

```
var keys = [];

for (var x in yourObj) {
    yourObj.hasOwnProperty(x) && keys.push(x);
}

keys.sort();

for (var i=0;i<keys.length;i++) {
    // use yourObj[keys[i]]; guaranteed to be in the right order
}
```

Of course, the [`sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) function on the Array object allows you to specify a function for a custom sort order. You can also use [`reverse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) to reverse the key order.