# Does jquery children() reads right to left?

Tags: jquery

If, on css we have:

```
#divitis>*
```

So *I believe*, it (the browser) will start reading all elements and then, check the #divitis element, so, it will go from *right* to *left*.

cf.
[Why do browsers match CSS selectors from right to left?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5797014/why-do-browsers-match-css-selectors-from-right-to-left)

My question is:

Does anyone knows if the `children()` jquery function works similarly, when we do:

```
$('#divitis').children()
```

Will it work from right to left:

1. Check all elements child of the child of the child;
2. Check all elements that are child of the child;
3. Check all elements that are child;
4. Grab the first children of #divitis;

OR, from left to right:

1. Scan all elements and search from #divitis;
2. Scan the first children of divitis;

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not overly clear what you're asking I'm afraid.

Comment: `children()` isn't a selector. Which bit do you mean that you want to read right to left?

Comment: I don't know about right to left(since the DOM is layed out top to bottom) but some quick tests would suggest that it does it top-bottom (the natural flow of the DOM).

Comment: Maybe this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9843142/change-in-order-for-each-in-firefox-and-chrome

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is the order objects are return by a jQuery selector specified?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636201/is-the-order-objects-are-return-by-a-jquery-selector-specified)

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario I'm not asking if there is of there isn't an order. I'm asking if that order, even if only eventually, is of certain kind, similar to the selectors on CSS. I guess I'm not asking the same.

Comment: @MEM - Ah, you are asking whether jQuery follows the W3C CSS specs regarding selectors. Well, it should, and it it doesn't then it's a bug.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario No, he's just asking in which order the individual terms within the selector string are parsed.

Answer (score 0):

`.children()` will only look at the direct children of your selector.
What you need is `.find()` instead, which in my experience will traverse the DOM tree "in order", so from "left to right", meaning direct children first, then children of children, and so on.

Added a little JSFiddle for clarification: http://jsfiddle.net/qbG7x/

Answer (score 0):

In your case where you've written `$('#divitis').children()`, you've actually got two different selectors, i.e. `#divitis` and `> *`.

However, because the two jQuery function calls are followed strictly in normal evaluation order, the `#divitis` selector will be evaluated first, and then `> *`.

This is therefore the *opposite* order to if this had been written just as a single selector containing `#divitis > *`.

That said, the reason why the browsers go R->L instead of L->R doesn't really apply here.

When applying a CSS style sheet it's more efficient to skip mismatching individual rules of  a CSS style sheet based on the rightmost element of each selector than on the leftmost element.

Here, though, you're programmatically "writing a single rule", so there's no "other rules" that need skipping.

Comment: I still don't get it, sorry. You said that the reason why browsers go R->L instead of L->R doesn't apply. But you also say that having `$('#divitis > *')` is the opposite order then `$('#divitis').children()` ... at the end, I didn't get if it works differently of not. Sorry, I'm not that proficient in English. At a first glass, I would say that `#divitis>*` may be slower then `$('#divitis').children()`

Comment: @MEM that would be my assessment - `#divitis > *` is slower than `#divitis .children()`.  The R->L order is there to allow the browser to trivially discard CSS rules that don't match.  In a line of jQuery code there are no "non-matching" rules, there's just one "rule".